# Vibrate iPhone for specified duration

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, ios4, vibration

I would like to be able to vibrate the iPhone for a specified duration. Using the AudioToolbox framework, it will vibrate for about 2 seconds, when I use this code:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

This does the job, but I'd rather vibrate for a shorter (or longer) duration depending on how the user performed the action, not to mention the benefits this could offer to game developers.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: THe point here is, I want to make the device vibrate shorter, not longer, and I'm sure most people will use common sense and/or judgement in using this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a NSTimer or a for loop that would set off a vibration every two seconds and make it seem like a long vibrate. Not sure if Apple would allow this tough.

Comment: Yeah, I was fearing this would be what I'd have to do, although this method doesn't allow for shorter vibrations.